# In Linux using C, how to write the entire environment to a file?

Tags: c, linux, file, overwrite

In Linux using C, how to write the entire environment to a file? The code must not overwrite the data already in the file? The result of the following program is only one line of the contents are written in the file.

How can I solve this problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

extern char** environ;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ff;
    char buffer[100];
    ff = open("file.txt", O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0600);
    if (ff == -1)
    {
        printf("Fail to create and open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    char **tmp = environ;
    while (*tmp != NULL){
        // printf("\n%s\n", *tmp);
        write(ff, ("\n%s\n", *tmp), 100);
        tmp++;
    }
    close(ff);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you're not to overwrite the data already in the file, you either need to seek to the end before starting to write, or you need to use `O_APPEND` in the flags to `open()`.  `O_APPEND` works better in that it always appends, even if another process (or file descriptor) is also writing to the same file, whereas the seek option does not handle those cases.

Comment: You should check out whether POSIX [`dprintf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dprintf.html)
is available to you.  Also, as things stand, you don't need `<sys/stat.h>` and with modern POSIX, you don't usually need `<sys/types.h>` either (and specifically you don't need it here).

Comment: What do you mean by "must not overwrite the data in the file"?  If you want to ensure that you're not overwriting an existing file, use `O_EXCL` in the open.  If you want to append to any existing file, use `O_APPEND`.  If you want to somehow merge the current contents of the file with what you're writing (eliminating duplicates), you'll need to do some sort of read/filter/rewrite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem

```
write(ff, ("\n%s\n", *tmp), 100);
```

the `,` operator discards all operands to the left leaving the last operand, `*tmp` it means that no new line character is being written.

Also, this line invokes undefined behavior because you don't know whether `*tmp` points to a 100 byte buffer or not, hard coding 100 is wrong.

You need something like this

```
char **tmp;
tmp = environ;
for (int i = 0 ; tmp[i] != NULL ; ++i)
{
    char newline;
    newline = '\n';

    write(ff, tmp[i], strlen(tmp[i]));
    write(ff, &newline, 1);        
}
```

And you should also try this

```
dprintf(ff, "%s\n", temp[i]);
```

which is available on Linux.

Comment: But the former contents are still be replaced by the new one. How to deal with this ?

Comment: @WBLee add `| O_APPEND` to the flags of your open flags.